# roll back SQL query executed by mistake

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, rollback

I think the question says it all,
the following update query has been executed - by mistake - in SQL Server management studio

```
update kms_students set student_campus='4' where student_campus='KL'
```

The effected rows are more than 1000, and i can't identify it since that table is already have the `student_campus='4'` for many previous rows.

Is it possible to roll back?

Comment: update kms_students set student_campus='KL' where student_campus='4'

Comment: @user1534664 that's may not be good as it might have a side effect.

Comment: if you've changed others that aren't KL you're pretty much screwed because you can't retreive deleted data unless you made a back up or there are logs, like preet says =)

Comment: This should be on dba - he needs to rollback some transaaction logs

Comment: @user1534664,  i can't identify it since that table is already have the student_campus='4' for many previous rows.

Comment: thats too bad =( you should try and check for transaction logs, that seems like the only option you have.

Comment: how to rollback the transaction logs?

Comment: This is not an easy restore, as was mentioned you need to first find out if you have transaction logs and that they go back to the last backup. Then you need to restore the backup and then reprocess the transactions in the transaction log. If you are not the dba for this database you are going to need to loop him in on this and probably your manager as this will cause a major outage.

Comment: @Codeguy007, I am the dba, and this query has been excuted by a developer here, the query is correct but the value 4 is not, However this is last executed query, Does this make different? is there any way to roll back the latest query?

Comment: Maybe you coud check out Log Rescue (http://stackoverflow.com/a/283332/1373170), however it only seems to be compatible with SQL2000, but you are on 2008, correct?

Comment: @PabloRomeo, It's just for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Then maybe this one: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log_features.aspx

Comment: @PabloRomeo, Wow! , I've recovered the data back in 5 Minutes, Thank you so much Pablo, ApexSQL is wonderful. Please answer this question.
 If ApexSQL can finds the new and the old values that means there is another way to do so in SQL MS, Right?

Comment: I'm glad it worked :D I'll add it as an answer then so you can accept it. Regarding your question, AFAIK ApexSQL is doing it by analyzing the physical transaction log which basically has all the necessary info to do that, but MS doesn't provide an out-of-box tool to manage it, other than restoring a backup and then manually restoring the transaction log up to a particular date using RESTORE LOGS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) should do the trick.

ApexSQL works by analyzing the physical transaction log which basically has all the necessary info to restore specific transactions and data, but MS doesn't provide an out-of-box tool to manage it, other than restoring a backup and then manually restoring the transaction log up to a particular date using [RESTORE LOGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup. Most Hosting companies keep one, try calling everyone asap.
2. Your own backups. Even if they're old they will be helpful.
3. Keep lots of Backups and NEVER try out queries on production environment. NEVER.(Bet you learned that, right?)

To make it a bit easier, you can try putting the backup DB online and execute some PHP/Python/whatever so as to compare each record from the Backup and change the current database fom '4' to 'KL' where needed.

May not be perfect, but can help you avoid a few days of work.